# How do I configure AT&T's Uverse 2Wire 2701HGV-B Gateway into DMZPlus Mode?

Tags: router, gateway

I subscribed for AT&T's Uverse service and they shipped me a Wire 2701HGV-B Router/Gateway/Firewall/WiFi.

I would like to configure AT&T's hardware to have less control and use my trusted Linksys WRT54-G router between my computers and the 2Wire Gateway. This seems to be a common configuration for Uverse users with this hardware in other forums, but requires a "DMZPlus" mode that I'm unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 3):

You can enter the Management and Diagnostic Console by going to

http://192.168.1.254/mdc

From there go to the edit firewall settings page

http://192.168.0.1/xslt?PAGE=J11&THISPAGE=J01&NEXTPAGE=J11

The third option should be "Allow all applications (DMZplus mode)"

Comment: Dave L., you just totally saved my night.  Thanks!